# Praying terrible things for a terrible person

Tags: halal-haram

I am 19 years old. 3 years ago, I was harassed by a man (I'm a woman) at a concert. I know going to a concert is haram and I regret it, so please don’t say anything on that. The guy was a lot older than me, he came behind me and rubbed his lower self against my backside no matter how many times I moved away, a girl beside me noticed as well and told me to make him leave. After the concert she told me he had done that to other girls as well, all of them were young. I’ve tried to forgive him and move on but I can’t, and sometimes my thoughts just go to him burning in hellfire.

**My question is:** Is it haram to pray for something like that for that type of person?

Comment: Islam allows praying against an evildoer.

Answer (score -1):

In the name of God, the Most Merciful, Most Just

Yes, you can pray for terrible things for that person because God Almighty Says:

> “So should anyone aggress against you, assail him in the manner he assailed you, and be wary of God, and know that God is with the Godwary.” [2:194]

But, it is much preferable if you don’t pray terrible things for that person and pray for God To Guide him to the right path, because God Almighty Says:

> Verily, the Hour is coming, so forgive them with gracious forgiveness.
>   Surah Al-Hijr 15:85

---

> Show forgiveness, enjoin what is good, and turn away from the ignorant.
>   Surah Al-A’raf 7:199

---

> The believers are those who spend in charity during ease and hardship and who restrain their anger and pardon the people, for God loves the doers of good.
>   Surah Ali Imran 3:134

---

> Abdullah ibn Amr (may God be pleased with him) reported:
>   The Messenger of God, peace and blessings be upon him, was upon the pulpit and he said:
>   ارْحَمُواتُرْحَمُواوَاغْفِرُوايَغْفِرْاللَّهُلَكُمْ
>   Be merciful to others and you will receive mercy. Forgive others and God will forgive you.

---

> O leader of the believers, God said to His Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him: Show forgiveness, enjoin what is good, and turn away from the ignorant (7:199). Verily, this man is ignorant.

1) Whoever does not show mercy will not receive mercy.

2) Whoever does not forgive others will not be forgiven.

3) Whoever does not pardon others will not be pardoned.

4) Whoever does not protect others will not be protected.

> “Say: O My slaves who have transgressed against themselves (by committing evil deeds and sins)! Despair not of the Mercy of God, verily, God forgives all sins. Truly, He is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful.” (Surah Az-Zumar 39:53)

---

> (Fear God! If a Believer does injustice to another Believer, God the most glorified will definitely take the revenge of the oppressed person on his oppressor on the Day of Resurrection.) [A.b. Hamid]

---

> (He who disobeys his parents and who wanders with the unjust is an evil doer. God the most glorified, the most high declares, “We undoubtedly take revenge on evil doers.”) [Tabarânî]

So this means that you have to live this up to God, and He will take revenge on that person on the Day of Judgment unless this person repents to God of what he did to you.

And God knows best